# Chartset encoding when using Ajax ? JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, character-encoding

I have a web application (UTF-8) in which the following one can be used to send to the server side

```
áéíóú
àèìòù
ÀÈÌÒÙ
ÁÉÍÓÚ
```

Ok. I use something like as follows to send data

```
// Notice $("#myForm").serialize()
$.get("/path?", $("#myForm").serialize(), function(response) {

});
```

When i see my recordSet, i get (database charSet encoding is UTF-8)

```
Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³Ãº
Ã Ã¨Ã¬Ã²Ã¹
ÃÃ‰ÃÃ“Ãš
Ã€ÃˆÃŒÃ’Ã™
```

Even when using $.post, i get the same result set

After seeing serialize() method in JQuery in Action book:

> Creates **a properly formatted and encoded query string** from all successful form elements in the wrapped set

But, as shown above, it does not appear to work fine. So instead of serialize() method, i use

```
var objectArray =  $("#myForm").serializeArray();

var queryString = "";
for(var i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
    queryString += "&" + objectArray[i]["name"] + "=" + objectArray[i]["value"];
}

$.get("/path?" + queryString, null, function(response) {

});
```

Now i get in database

```
áéíóú
àèìòù
ÀÈÌÒÙ
ÁÉÍÓÚ
```

So Am i missing something when using serialize() method ? Why serialize() method does not work as expected ?

Answer (score 5):

I resolve it in PHP with the following line:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_POST[$key] = utf8_decode($value);
}
```

Comment: This did help me alot!

Answer (score 3):

`jQuery.get` like all the functions jQuery ajax use `encodeURIComponent` for the data.
If you send data via GET, the XHR automatically takes care of passing the encoding of URLs.
You can view the documentation of [`encode`](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/) to see which type of encoding is suitable for the data you send

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with IE. I added to pageload javascript the following:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
       contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
});
```

Which seemed to solve the issue with most chars.

Comment: use of ajaxSetup is discouraged (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/).
but contentType can be passed directly in $.ajax() call.
to me this answer was helpfull, because event if the ajax request is encoded correctly in ut8, called may not understand that its utf8

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following meta tag to the head of both the initiating and receiving page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

This will default the page to render content in utf-8. If this alone doesn't work you can use `encodeURIComponent()` in addition to encode the characters when sending. If need be on the receiving end if the encoding isn't automatically decoded, run `decodeURIComponent()`.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize does not work with IE and ISO-8859-1 chars.

See http://forum.jquery.com/topic/serialize-problem-with-latin-1-iso-8859-1-and-solution

I also add the test

```
if( $.browser.msie )
```

Because in FF works and this hack doesnt work.